# Why DBLookup isn't a custom endpoint rather than mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

The DBLookup construct is implemented as mediator in WSO2. Are there any reasons why this wasn't implemented as Customer Endpoint rather?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to think about EPs is to consider them a final destination for your data, while mediators are intermediate stops where they will be modified and/or enriched.

The DBLookup, in particular, was primarily tought as a way to enrich a given message with data recovered from a database (hence its name).

In theory, one could write a custom endpoint to send received messages directly a database. However, WSO2 has its DSS product which covers this kind of scenario and it is much more flexible.